# How to Collect the line with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to know how I can collect line, mailto link using selenium python the emails contains @ sign in the contact page I tried the following code but it is somewhere works and somewhere not..

```
//*[contains(text(),"@")]
```

the emails formats are different somewhere it is `<p>Email: name@domain.com</p>` or `<span>Email: name@domain.com</span>` or `<a href="mailto:name@domain.com">name@domain.com</a>`

is there anyway to collect them with one statement..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the XPath you are looking for my friend.

```
//*[contains(text(),"@")]|//*[contains(@href,"@")]
```

Comment: having the same issue somewhere it works and on some sites it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You could create a collection of the link text values that contain @ on the page and then iterate through to format. You are going to have to format the span like that has Email: name@domain.com anyway.

Use find_elements_by_partial_link_text to make the collection.

Comment: I did both using xpath and link_text but doesn't work

Comment: That is because it seems that some of the elements you want are via <A> tags and others are spans or Email. I am guessing your xpath will work for some and link text will work for others.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 XPath. First XPath for finding element that contains text "Email:", second XPath for element that contains attribute "mailto:".

```
//*[contains(text(),"Email:")]|//*[contains(@href,"mailto:")]
```